# How to list file names with a total of X letters

Tags: grep, ls, regex

Say I have a list of the following files in my current dir:

`lab1.jav`  `mytst2`  `pie.c`    `prog2.c`  `tst3.ex`   `tst5:5.tlab2jav`  `lab2jav.ext`  `new.c`   `prog1.c`  `tst1`     `tst4.ex`c  `tst6:6123.tA7-tst.c`    `fred.txt`

And I need to list the files with a total of say 7 letters for example. How would you do this?
I tried to no avail:

```
ls | egrep -i '[a-z]{7}'
```

I think it's because the dots are in the way, is there a simple way of doing this?

Comment: Whats your expected output?

Comment: Your question is incomplete and suffers from ambiguity because you have not responded to heemayl's request for your desired output based on your sample filenames.  This lack of clarity prevents volunteers from confidently providing accurate, working solutions for your specific task. @Sammy  It would also make your question easier to read if you listed the filenames vertically (on separate lines inside of a single, code-formatted block).

Comment: I've already marked the answer I was looking for as solved. Should be clear if you read the answer @mickmackusa

Comment: A "good" question's clarity should never leverage other posts on the same page -- it should stand up entirely on its own. Researchers should not have to read any comments or answers to understand the question. You can trust me, I'm not tricking you.  I am new to AskUbuntu, but not Stack Exchange.

Comment: This comment under the answer makes your question Unclear to me.  `I tried ls | grep -Ei '^[a-z]{7}$' and got nothing, I should at least get fred.txt I haven't tried with sed however.`

Comment: Are you inquiring @mickmackusa because you have the same or similar question?

Comment: I am a self-taught developer with underdeveloped server / command line skills.  I am diving into AskUbuntu questions that are tagged with [php] and [regex] tags (because this is where my comfort lies). While wandering through the pages, I am voting to close, suggesting edits, voting, and leaving comments which will benefit AskUbuntu posters and researchers.  I make these valuable contributions because I care about Stack Exchange and its monumental influence on researchers.  Please comply with my very simple request.

Comment: Sorry @mickmackusa I don't think I can help, this question was asked in 2016 regarding a Linux computer science homework question, so I don't remember the context to answer your questions unfortunately. If you want to take it down even though it has benefited me/other people, go ahead.

Comment: Or perhaps you would consider editing my question so it's up to your standards? Someone understood it enough to provide an answer was my point, but I agree the question could be better written.

Comment: So you cannot look at your sample input and your requirements and show the desired output? Where I am getting tripped up (which is why I am not qualified to suggest an edit) is that your pattern does not contain a literal dot.  So is your filter disregarding file extensions? This is Unclear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done this way:

```
ls | grep -E '^(\W*[0-9]*[a-zA-Z]){7}\W*[0-9]*$'
```

This includes cases when the first and the last character is a digit or a non alphanumeric char.

Or shorter

```
ls | grep -Ei '^([^a-z]*[a-z]){7}[^a-z]*$'
```

Comment: It has to match only the letters, not the numbers or other characters like '.' and ':'

Comment: Sounds like a job for `sed`, no?

Comment: @SammyGuergachi Made for only letters

Comment: I tried `ls | grep -Ei '^[a-z]{7}$'` and got nothing, I should at least get `fred.txt` I haven't tried with `sed` however.

Comment: Note that the results will also include folders. `ls -d| grep -E '^[a-zA-Z]{7}$'` will include files only

Comment: Spaces in the filename will also fail to match even if they have 7 letters no?

Comment: Probably? I'm new to regex so I'm still learning a lot of these rules.

Comment: This will not work exactly as required. It will not match `aaaaa.aaa`. It is more complex. Is it a homework?

Comment: Yes! Maybe the homework question is not correct.

Comment: Think about how you would construct a regex *atom* consisting of an alphabetic character followed by zero or more non-alphabetic characters